# Functions $f$ such that $A$ and $f(A,B)$ are independent

Tags: pr.probability

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are two dependent random variables. Are there any results on functions $f$ such that 
$C =f(A, B)$ and $A$ are independent?

For example, it can easily be shown that  $A$ and $C = F_{B|A}(B, A)$ are independent where $F_{B|A}(., .)$ is the conditional CDF function of $B$, given $A$. (I am using the conditional CDF as a function of two random variables). This is called the Darmois decomposition in the signal processing literature.

So $A$ and $h\Big(F_{B|A}(B, A)\Big)$ are also independent where $h$ is a measurable function.

Are there any other functions such that $C =f(A, B)$ and $A$ are independent?

Comment: I don’t think all the examples are of the type that you suggest. As an example: if $A$ and $B$ are independent Unif[0,1] random variables and $C=(A+B)\bmod 1$, then this is not of the form you’re looking for.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Doesn't the assumption state that $A$ and $B$ are dependent?

Comment: I read it as “not necessarily independent”. Pretty evidently, this doesn’t change anything. If you insist on having non-independence, then take $(A,B)$ uniform on $[0,1]\times [0,1]\cup [1,2]\times[1,2]$.

Comment: The answer to your second question is "no", they will not be of that form.  The domain of an inverse CDF cannot be bigger than $[0,1]$ while presumably $B$ can take values outside this

Comment: @Henry: I think the $h$ can do the rescaling.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I think that is insufficient, if $F^{-1}_{B\mid A}(B\mid A)$ is supposed to mean anything

Comment: @Henry: I’m not understanding here. If $h(x)=200x-100$, then $C=h(F_{B|A}(B))$ takes uniform values in the range $-100$ to 100, independent of $A$ (as long as the conditional distribution of B|A is almost surely non-atomic). So the fact that the range may not lie inside $[0,1]$ is not an obstruction to the conjectured form of $C$ (but the example I gave is an example of a $C$ that is not of the required form).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas You wrote $C=h(F_{B|A}(B))$ while the OP wrote $h(F^{-1}_{B|A}(B|A))$.  My point was related to the implications of $\,^{-1}$ and the *inverse* CDF

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must say that I don't quite understand your notation. There is a complete description of the independent complements in the sense you are asking, but I prefer to formulate it in somewhat different terms, namely in the language of Lebesgue spaces and their measurable partitions due to [Rokhlin](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=30584). The base probability space in this problem is the joint distribution of $A$ and $B$; let us denote this space by $(X,m)$. Then the random variable $A$ is a function on the space $X$. By one of Rokhlin's theorems, if the distribution of $A$ and almost all conditional distributions of $B$ are purely non-atomic, then the space $(X,m)$ can be identified with the unit square endowed with the Lebesgue measure, and $A$ with the projection of this square onto the first coordinate. Then in this setup you are asking about functions $C$ on the unit square endowed with the Lebesgue measure which are independent of the first coordinate. They are all of the form
$$
C(x_1,x_2) = \phi ( \Psi^{x_1} (x_2)) \;,
$$
where $\Psi^{x_1}$ is a measurable family of automorphisms of the unit interval, and $\phi$ is a measurable function on the unit interval.

Comment: Sorry for possible ambiguities. I have edited my question to make it more clear.